# Lost all resolutions with Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 18.04

I've Kubuntu 18.04

My monitor supports 1920x1080, but today when I turn on PC, I see only 1280x1024 avaible.

lspci give me this

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

xrandr give me this

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024 default
connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm    1280x1024     77.00*
```

I can't add new resolution - I always get "Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:"

If I boot with liveCD, all is OK, resolution is 1920x1080.

How I can refresh this drivers, or remove and then install again.

Or anyway to fix this :).

Thanks in advance.